# laravel new column default value created_at value

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table with orders like:

**Order**

```
id
created_at
shipped_at
billed_at
```

the shipped_at is on the packing list and the billed_at on the invoice.The fields shipped_at and billed_at are recently added.

When I create the order sometimes I want to give the created_at date a custom date if the order is for the future (i know this wasnt the original idea behind created_at). What I want is that the value of created_at is copied to shipped_at and billed_at on creation, because i sometimes use a custom value for created_at I cant just use current date time.

I can create an Order on 5 different locations so it would be nice if I could just create one function to copy these values instead of call the same function from 5 locations where i create an order.

Is there a clever location in the laravel framework to copy the value of created_at to shipped_at?

***thoughts:***
Normaly I would think an event like saving would be best but the created_at is created after the save, is it possible to update/save in the saved event or would this create an infinit loop of saving?

Comment: Have you tried using the `created` event? That should trigger after the creation, whereas `creating` is during.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to aynber comment to use the created event I came up with the following solution:

in command line

```
php artisan make:provider OrderDatesProvider
```

to create a new provider. In the provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class OrderDatesProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        Order::created(function($order){
            $order->shipped_at = $order->created_at;
            $order->billed_at = $order->created_at;
            $order->save();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```